# How to perform sequential tasks having asynchronous subtasks

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

I am facing the following problem as part of my Android development:

I need to perform sequential tasks but my problem come from the fact that each task has asynchronous subtasks. Before executing the next task, I need to be sure the last task finished (that means, all asynchronous subtasks also finished).

I am planning to combine the followings solutions:

(1) `ThreadPool` with a fixed number of threads set to "1". However, that doesn't prevent the next task to be executed after each asynchronous subtasks has finished.

(2) `BlockingQueue` inside each task with a call to the blocking `take()` method that wait for a finished information from the asynchronous subtask.

I find this handmade method not very clean and error prone.

Anyone knows a better solution ? Or maybe a lib that solve elegantly this problem ?

Comment: RxJava should allow you to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage RxJava to easily do this:

```
Observable
    .concat(
        Observable.fromCallable(() -> yourAsyncTask1()),
        Observable.fromCallable(() -> yourAsyncTask2()))
    .subscribeOn(androidSchedulers.io())
    .observeOn(androidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(() -> {
        doSomethingAfterBothFinished();
    });
```

RxJava even allows you to easily handle errors with `onError`.

If one task depends on the other you can use `map`:

```
Observable
    .fromCallable(() -> yourAsyncTask1())
    .map((ResultType1 result1) -> {
        return yourAsyncTask2(result1);
    })
    .subscribeOn(androidSchedulers.io())
    .observeOn(androidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(() -> {
        doSomethingAfterBothFinished();
    });
```

Where `result1` is the returned value from `yourAsyncTask1()`.

Note that everything above `subscribeOn()` will be done on a background thread, wheres everything below `observeOn()` will be done on the mainThread. this is very helpful if you want to update your UI after the tasks finished, since that can only be done on the mainThread